# signin-oidc flow throws 500 in chrome but not IE

Tags: google-chrome, .net-core, openid-connect, http-status-code-500

I have a `netcoreapp2.1` webapp which is presenting an issue in Google Chrome, but not Edge or IE, during the `OIDC flow` redirect. It simply stops at `http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc` with this response received:

**General:**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: [::1]:5000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

**Response Headers:**

```
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 04 Aug 2020 09:49:32 GMT
Server: Kestrel
```

**Request Headers:**

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2148
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:5000
Origin: null
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36
```

**Form Data:**

```
code: Ry9Pec...rdG1U0SB
scopes: resource.WRITE+openid+resource.READ
state: CfDJ8JZ...oESbUvQ
id_token: eyJhbG...9sXMEhs
```

When I visit localhost:5000 in chrome (incognito or not) the code never reaches the `OnTicketReceived` event, whereas when fired from IE, Edge etc it does, and proceeds just fine.

This is the startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    private AppSettings _appSettings;
    private IConfiguration _config;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _config = configuration;
        _appSettings = _config.Get<AppSettings>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(_config);

        services.AddSingleton<IAPIRepository, APIRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<INavigationRepository, NavigationRepository>();

        services.UseOpenIDConnectMiddleware(new OpenIDConnectMiddlewareOptions
        {
            BaseUrl = _appSettings.API.BaseUrl,
            AppName = _appSettings.AppName,
            ClientId = _appSettings.API.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = _appSettings.API.ClientSecret,
            Secure = !_appSettings.Local
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        
        if (!_appSettings.Local)
        {
            app.UseGlobalLoginMiddleware();
        }

        if (_appSettings.FeatureFlags["ProcessRedirectionRules"])
        {
          app.UseRedirectUserMiddleware(_appSettings.RedirectionRules);
        }
        
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseProtectHTMLRouteMiddleware();

        if (_appSettings.Local)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
                ProjectPath = Path.Join(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "../UI"),
                ConfigFile = "node_modules/@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js",
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseJavascriptVarMiddleware(new JavascriptSettingsMiddlewareOptions 
        {
            FileName = "env.js",
            ObjectName = "__env",
            Settings = new Dictionary<string, string> 
            {
                { "insightsKey", _appSettings.ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey },
                { "environment", _appSettings.Environment },
                { "gatekeeperBaseUrl", _appSettings.Gatekeeper.BaseUrl }
            }
        });

        app.UseGlobalSignoutMiddleware(new GlobalSignoutMiddlewareOptions 
        {
            GatekeeperLogoutUrl = _appSettings.API.LogoutUrl
        });

        app.UseHTMLRouteFallback(new HTMLRouteFallbackMiddlewareOptions 
        {
            Local = _appSettings.Local,
            Path = Path.Join(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "../UI/dist")
        });
    }
}
```

I have cleaned the `localhost` and `localhost:5000` cookies from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess would be that it is a SameSite cookie issue that different browsers handle differently due to various bugs.

This article might give you a starting point:

- [How To Prepare Your IdentityServer For Chrome's SameSite Cookie Changes - And How To Deal With Safari, Nevertheless](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/identity/samesite/prepare-your-identityserver/)

Also, your Configure method looks very odd. Because the ordering of the App.Use statements matter and usually you would put the app.UseMvc(); last in that method. Each incoming request will pass through those middlewares that the App.UseXXX adds and if the ordering is not correct then you will have issues.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)

Comment: I don't think so... I'm receiving a 500 internal server error and there is no x-site or cookie mention in the console at all. The only entry with a warning or error is the http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc - How else might I verify that this is the cookie issue?

Comment: I should mention that other developers on my team also use Chrome and are not experiencing this issue.

Comment: aha, ok.  The SameSite issue might result in cookies not being included. But you should try to look at the logs to get what error you get.

Comment: There are no logs rn - the app is running on my machine and I'm not even hitting any debug stop points. I will check the API log where the /oauth/authorize call is made but that is returning 200 OK, so I don't expect to find anything.

Comment: I am sure you can enable logs (either to Visual Studio outout window or the console) , perhaps also add app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); at the start of the Configure method.